# Animated CSS Text Underline

Tags: html, css, animation, text-decorations

I have created this animated underline, but the bottom seems to sit still whilst everything else moves - making it look **"laggy"**

I created a codepen to illustrate the issue. 
Do you have any idea why is this happening?

[Codepen for illustration](https://codepen.io/katrine-mira-arndt-lind/pen/VwYGmxZ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span class="divider-body">
<div class="divider-wave" data-text="dividerdivider"></div>
</span>

</body>
</html>


<style type="text/css">
.divider-body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.divider-wave {
    width: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.divider-wave:before {
content: attr(data-text);
position: relative;
top: -42px;
color: white;
font-size: 4em;
text-decoration-style: wavy;
text-decoration-color: #607d8b;
text-decoration-line: underline;
animation: animate 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate 
{
0%
{
    left: 0;
}
100% 
{
    left: -30px;
}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the line issue (without regard to actual browser support), try to use the `text-decoration-line: line-through;` property and value. I changed the positioning for demonstration purpose.

```css
.divider-body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.divider-wave {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.divider-wave:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  text-decoration-color: #607d8b;
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
  animation: animate 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divider-body">
  <span class="divider-wave" data-text="dividerdivider" />
</div>
```

I would also suggest swapping the `span` and `div`, since a `span` can only contain phrasing content, [as described here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) See a [list of content categories here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Answer (score 0):

The text-decoration-style: wavy; doesn't have great support:
https://caniuse.com/#search=text%20decoration%20style%20wavy

I'd suggest doing this as a background image with background-repeat: repeat; and animate the background-position property.

Backgrounds will animate a lot smoother.

Answer (score 0):

A short inspect shows that the line is moved back, which causes the problem. This happens on the left side as well, but by moving the line out of the container, it is no longer visible. The solution is simple; the width of the container should be the length of the line minus the moving distance of the line.

```
width: 1130px;
```

Visual: https://codepen.io/Toeffe3/pen/MWYqJyz

[image]